# Access modifiers and hiding Java fields

Tags: java, overriding, field, access-modifiers, member-hiding

This is a follow-up to the question: ["java access modifiers and overriding"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851612/java-access-modifiers-and-overriding). The former generally deals with Java methods however. Why the flexibility with Java fields? We can narrow or widen the visibility with their respect in an inherited class whereas can't with an 'overridden' nor 'hidden' method.

Comment: Please post a link to that question

Comment: fields are not overridden. They are just hidden.

Comment: thanks adarshr                                   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851612/java-access-modifiers-and-overriding

Comment: updated the title of previous question to reflect methods() as hiding fields is shunned it seem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851612/java-access-modifiers-and-overriding-methods

Comment: It appears that it's not about hiding/overriding when it comes to access modifiers. I just tried hiding methods and the same visibility rules apply. I still can't reduce the visibility on an inherited static method(). What's the difference between fields and methods()?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When overriding a method, why can I increase access but not decrease it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851612/when-overriding-a-method-why-can-i-increase-access-but-not-decrease-it)

Comment: @double-beep That question is about methods, this one is about fields. It is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

You never *override* fields to start with - you're *always* hiding them. Fields aren't polymorphic... in other words, if you write:

```
Superclass x = new Subclass();
System.out.println(x.field);
```

and both `Superclass` and `Subclass` declare a field called `field`, it will *always* use the superclass one anyway, because that's all the compiler can "see".

Personally I try to keep my variables private anyway...

Comment: Which is one of the many reasons I *love* properties in .Net - they look and feel like field, but can still be polymorphic.

Answer (score 2):

> why the flexibility with java fields

You cannot make a field in another class go private by extending it. When you make a new field in a sub class you are just hiding the super class field.

```
class Base {
    protected int x;
}

class Ext extends Base {
    private int x; // not the same as Base.x
}
```

Comment: Of course you can make a field private. I think you mean you can't change the access of a field in the base class by providing a private field in the subclass... but I suggest you clarify your answer.