# extending an abstract class with generic enum type

Tags: java, enums

Is there a way to extend an abstract class with generic enum types? When I extend it and implement myMethod below, only the method from the abstract class gets called.

1. first i define abstract class with method myMethod where i would like to make decisions based on the enum value.

   ```
   public abstract class MyAbstractClass <T extends enum<T>> {

       public void myMethod(T cmd) {
         //i want to override this
       }

       public void update(T cmd) {
         myMethod(cmd);
       }
   }
   ```
2. define an enum and extend the class, but the child class myMethod never gets called(only the myMethod of abstract class gets called).

   ```
   enum CMD {
      CMD_1, CMD_2
   }

   public class Child extends MyAbstractClass<CMD> {
   ...
     public void myMethod(CMD cmd) {
       if (cmd == CMD_1) { //do something }
     }
   ...
   }
   ```
3. instantiate and call

   ```
   Child child = new Child();
   child.update(CMD.CMD_1);
   ```

Comment: Could you add the code that calls `myMethod`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I override a private method in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623913/can-i-override-a-private-method-in-java)

Comment: thx for the link..if i correct my code to make it public it still doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Use the construction suggested by @Bohemian. With the method which override the base one declared protected or public it must work.

Comment: What is `enum<T>`? Perhaps you meant `Enum<T>`? Did you actually try to compile the code you posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Use `T extends Enum<T>`:

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass <T extends Enum<T>> {
    public void myMethod(T cmd) {}
}
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/xmqida) of your code, with this change, compiling OK.

Comment: thx for getting back, but my initial post wasn't too clear so i edited it.  actually my issue is when i extend the abstract class and try to use CMD to make a decision on actions to perform. myMethod, which i override, never gets called.  instead the parent implementation gets called.

Comment: @prostock the overridden method *does* get called. See updated link with demo code proving this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select the behaviour according to the enum value, then one way to do it is to put the behaviour into each enum value, e.g.:

```
enum Command {
    CMD1 {
        @Override
        void execute() {
            System.out.println("Command.CMD1");
        }
    },
    CMD2 {
        @Override
        void execute() {
            System.out.println("Command.CMD2");
        }
    };

    abstract void execute();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Command cmd = Command.CMD1;

    cmd.execute();
}
```