# Why can the level access of a field or method be more accessible in a java subclass

Tags: java, access-modifiers

So as far as I understand the Substitution principle doesn't allow a subclass to have fields which have a weaker access privilege because otherwise it could potentially violate information hiding and also because a subclass should always offer at least the same behavior of its parent one. That makes sense to me.
but at the same time I don't understand how it could make sense to extend a field or method access level? I have a private field in the parent class while public in the child class. Could you give me an example of why this makes sense? Or is it just because of a design choice?

Comment: It can be with a method too, the same thing applies.

Comment: If a parent has a private field then the child doesn't have access to it. The child making a public variable with the same name is no problem.

Comment: You can't change the access level of a field; you can only hide it and define a new field with the same name (which is a can of worms you should normally avoid). Are you talking about methods instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java access modifiers and overriding methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851612/java-access-modifiers-and-overriding-methods)

Answer (score 1):

it is not true as you mentioned for private field. you can't extend a private field from super class to subclass. if you declare a field with that same name, you define a new field for that subclass.
However, you can change package access and protected access to something more like public and this doesn't make any problem because super class doesn't provide that for it's subclass but subclass maybe change its behavior depend on its state and wants to provide that for other users.
For example when it protected you can only access that in that package and in subclass. however maybe you do some works in it that doesn't good for public implementation. (if you make something public, you must support it for future release) however in subclass you might want to override it and add some new feature to it and provide a result that is usable by other people.
A good example (always java provide best example):
If you see, java declared this in Object class:

```
class Object {
    protected native Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException;
}
```

so no one can call `clone()` on it. it is good because maybe I don't want to provide `clone()` for my class. however if I want it, it is easy to override that and make it public for other people and also call `super.clone()` in it for use feature which is implemented before for create a new copy of my class. Isn't great?!

Comment: _"if you declare the same field with that name, you will define it for subclass with public level access"_ I suggest to change that to _"if you declare a field with that same name, you define a new field for that subclass"_.

Comment: Thanks @MarkRotteveel for better sentence.

Comment: @Amin Yes I realize the example with private -> public was bad but what about a method which is protected in the superclass and public in the subtype. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

> it could potentially violate information hiding

Information hiding, while a good practice, has little to do with the Liskov substitution principle.

> (A) subclass should always offer at least the same behavior of its parent (class).

This is true, but is achieved by disallowing a *stricter* access modifier on an inherited member. A *weaker* access modifier surfaces additional behavior.

```
class A {
    private int lastInput;
    protected int getLastInput() {
        return lastInput;
    }
    public int getSquareValue(int input) {
        lastInput = input;
        return getLastInput()*getLastInput();
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public int getLastInput() {
        return super.getLastInput();
    }
}

A aa = new A();
B bb = new B();
A ab = bb;

// All behaviors of A exist in B as well.
// B can be substituted for A.
System.out.println(aa.getSquareValue(5)); // 25
System.out.println(ab.getSquareValue(5)); // 25

// B also has new behaviors that A did not surface.
// This does not prevent B from substituting for A.
System.out.println(bb.getLastInput()); // 5
```

Comment: Thank you. So it is not possible to have a parent class with a protected method and a sub class with the same method as public?

Comment: No. It is possible to have a parent class with a protected method that a sub class overrides using a public method in Java.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html

The parent and child have 2 separate instances of test.  As you can see in this example.

```
public class Main {

    public class Parent{
        private String test = "parent test";

        String getTest() {
            return test;
        }
    }

    public class Child extends Parent {
        public String test = "child test";  // defining it here hides the parent field

        @Override
        String getTest() {
            return test;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        Parent parent = main.new Parent();
        System.out.println(parent.getTest());

        Child child = main.new Child();
        System.out.println(child.getTest());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
parent test
child test
```