# Why can't we change the access modifier of the static method in the subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, static, overriding

Since we cannot override static methods of the superclass in the subclass. Although we can have the same method with same signature in the subclass but that thing is method hiding.

So how come we are not able to change the access modifier of the static methods in the subclass. Why does it follow the method overriding rules of changing the access modifier?

```
class Vehicle {
   public static void staticMethod() {}
}


class Car extends Vehicle {
  public static void staticMethod() {} 
}
```

I tried to change the access modifier of `staticMethod()` in the subclass, but it was giving error
`java: staticMethod() in inheritance.example1.Car cannot override staticMethod() in inheritance.example1.Vehicle attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public`

we can only have the `public` access modifier in `staticMethod()` of the subclass (in this case).
We cannot change it to `private,` default or `protected`.

I am confused about this behaviour of `staticMethod()`.

Comment: _...but it was giving error..._ What is the error?

Comment: Also - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6851673/6650475).

Comment: From [§8.4.8.3 Requirements in Overriding and Hiding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3) of the Java Language Specification: "*The access modifier of an overriding or **hiding** method must provide at least as much access as the overridden or **hidden** method*". Though that doesn't tell you why it was defined to work like that.

Comment: it would cause some inconsistency/confusion: code like `Car.staticMethod()` in a different package is expected to call the method of `Car`, since a static method, but not allowed by modifier; should it call the public one of `Vehicle`, as would be the case if it was not hidden? (just my guess, I was not involved in the specification/development of Java)

Comment: Hi, sorry, I edited the post with the error message.

Comment: I know we cannot change the access modifier to something weaker in the subclass. But my question is why we are not allowed to do so.
Static methods are meant to be called using classname, but even if we are calling it with instance variable, the decision to call exactly which class static method is determined at the compile time. So there is no issue inconsistency or ambiguity here.

Comment: Why would you hide something that is already made public? it will cause problem for the consumer of the method that already made public. Another issue is in polymorphism, if a method's parameter is the parent class, and you pass a child class as argument, the child class may not aware the private method is called through the parent (public). Risky if not dangerous.

Answer (score 3):

Static methods are inherited¹. While they can not be overridden but only hidden, the considerations are still similar to overridable methods.

When you have class definitions like

```java
class Vehicle {
    public static void staticMethod() {}
}
class Car extends Vehicle {
}
```

The invocation `Car.staticMethod()` is valid.

It’s, by the way, not true that the decision for the actually invoked method is made at compile-time. Like with instance methods, the compiler will look up inherited methods for verifying the validity of the invocation but use the formal target type in the created binary. In other words, the class file will still contain an invocation of `Car.staticMethod()` in this example.

The JVM will determine at runtime that the invocation `Car.staticMethod()` has to end up at `Vehicle.staticMethod()`, typically on the first invocation. In other words, if the definition of `Car` is changed to contain a `public static void staticMethod()`, without recompiling the other classes, the invocation will end up at the new method at runtime.

---

What would happen if we were allowed to add a `private static void staticMethod() {}` to the class `Car`?

One point of view is that private things should be invisible to the outside and not affect other classes. When following this idea, the external caller of `Car.staticMethod()` would continue to be valid and end up at `Vehicle.staticMethod()`, with the disadvantage that `Car.staticMethod()` then means different things, depending on whether it’s inside the `Car` class or outside the class.

The alternative is to say that `Car.staticMethod()` always has to end up at the `Car` class’s method if there is one, even if this makes the method invocation invalid. In that case, external callers of `Car.staticMethod()` would cease to be valid, despite the `Car` class inherits a `staticMethod()` which the external caller could invoke.

As weird as that may sound, it’s exactly what happens in case of fields or inner classes. When we have

```
static class Superclass {
    public static int staticField = 1;
}

static class Subclass extends Superclass {
}
```

and an external accessor

```
int i = Subclass.staticField;
```

Java allows us to add an incompatible field like

```
static class Subclass extends Superclass {
    private static int staticField = 2;
}
```

which would invalidate the external access.

---

We can only guess why the language designers decided to define different behavior for fields and methods, but there’s [a hint in the language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.4.8):

> Widely distributed programs should not expose any fields to their clients. Apart from the binary compatibility issues discussed below, this is generally good software engineering practice. Adding a field to a class may break compatibility with pre-existing binaries that are not recompiled.

So the language supports exposing fields but it’s not considered the recommended practice. The language designers accepted potential binary compatibility issues with fields but focused on supporting evolution of APIs composed of methods, allowing to move methods up and down the type hierarchy and/or inserting new types into the hierarchy in a backward compatible manner. At this point, the stricter rules help keeping APIs backwards compatible.

---

¹ For completeness, static methods of interfaces, introduced with Java 8, are not inherited. Hence, method declarations in classes implementing them are entirely independent and thus, you can declare methods like

```java
interface SuperInterface {
    public static void staticMethod() {}
}

static class ImplementingClass implements SuperInterface {
    private static void staticMethod() {}
}
```

Comment: The other answer was deleted, so I couldn't respond to your comment, but thanks for the clarification. I was under the impression that static methods were not truly inherited and `Car.staticMethod()` would just be syntactic sugar for `Vehicle.staticMethod()` (i.e., the byte code would be as if you wrote the latter, not the former) if `Car` did not have a static method with that signature _visible_ to the caller. I find it an odd design choice to have static methods actually be inherited, but that's beside the point.

Comment: @Slaw well, at least in hindsight, I’d consider it a design mistake too. The original thoughts were not bad but we rarely see a benefit in practice. So the disadvantages dominate. It’s great that they decided for no inheritance in case of static interface methods.

Comment: Thanks for this great insight and clarification. Also, the case of inheritance with the Interface was something new to me.